# DB Connect failure python cx_Oracle - ORA-01804

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I try to connect oracle DB with cx_Oracle package in python 3.9.7.
cx_Oracle version is 8.3.0.

when i try to connect with command **cx_Oracle.clientversion()**  i got error :

***DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804***

Linux Os , attach  my *.bash_profile*

with sqlplus command i success to connect the DB.

***.bash_profile*** :

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when there is a discrepancy between the value of the environment variable `ORACLE_HOME` and the actual library that was loaded. You can set the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value `64` and run your script. It will tell you which method was used to load the library. If that doesn't help you figure it out, paste the output in your question and I'll try to help further.

Note as well that there is a new driver available (python-oracledb) which doesn't require Oracle Client libraries and therefore shouldn't run into this issue. Take a look here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a

Comment: Just set the environvment variable before running your code. On Linux that would be done with `export DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL=64`.

Comment: this error
**load by OS failure: /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libclntsh.so: cant open shared object: No such file or directory**
i copy the file to dir and it still the same error:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/OracleTools/19.0.0/lib/
check module directory
module name is /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
load in dir /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages load with name /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libclntsh.so
load by OS successful
validating loaded library
Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

Comment: It always checks that location (the directory where the module is found) but it isn't necessary to use. If you do use it, though, you need to copy more than just that file. Are you using an instant client or a full Oracle client?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/632